# Setting charging limit on MBP?

Tags: macos, power-management

Is it possible to tweak settings so that the battery will only charge up to 90% -95% and then use power adapter to run ?

A friend told me he was able to set such limits on his non-mac PC so I was hoping there would be a way to do it. From reading I have done online it appears this is better than having a 100% battery most of the time.

I have an MBP 13" 2012 running latest version of OSX ML(10.8.2).

Comment: You might want to try using [Watts](http://binarytricks.com/) - configurable reminders to calibrate your battery, take it off AC after too long, etc.  I found it well worth the purchase price.

Answer (score 2):

The logic for doing what you want is already hard-coded into the battery and its internal charging circuits. Not only is pretty much every laptop on the market today doing this, but I imagine it's not something you can change, either. (Commenting from personal experience, I've seen this behavior in every laptop I've owned or had loaned to me over the past 6 years-- Two Dells, two MBPs, and a Lenovo)

When it comes to proper care of laptop batteries these days, the only real advice that an end-user can take is

> Store the battery in a cool, dry place when it's not being used, and don't heat it up while it's charging.

<sup>Yes, that means you probably don't want to use the laptop while the battery is charging.</sup>

Pretty much every other detail with regards to charging cycles or the implementation thereof have been gone over by experts that study batteries for a living, and are likely already tailored to your battery far better than any generic internet advice will give you.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here in the modern era, there are quite a few updates. For one, as of 10.15.5, Apple is introducing Battery Health Management to do this sort of thing automatically: https://www.slashgear.com/macbook-charging-is-changing-as-macos-gets-smarter-about-batteries-16617057/

If you're using a Mac on 10.15 Catalina or newer and you'd like more control, the following two projects will let you set peak charge capacity:

https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente
https://github.com/sicreative/BatteryStatusShow

If you're on an older Mac or you're already an Alfred user, I put together a quick workflow that lets you set either 70% or 100%:
https://www.alexwhittemore.com/controlling-macbook-pro-charging-cap-with-alfred/
This post also contains a ton more info on battery charging and options.

Finally, especially in the era of USB-C Macs, options abound for less-powerful charger bricks to charge your machine slower for less wear. I personally use a 61w normally, and only use the 87 if I specifically need the power for a heavy workload. Even 30w might be a good choice for charging overnight. But stick with name-brands: many a MacBook has been destroyed by a no-name 87w USB-C supply.